# ffplay startup time proportional to specified framerate

Tags: ffmpeg

I am playing a video over http using ffplay. The call I am using looks like this:

```
ffplay -framerate 30 -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -autoexit -i http://localhost:8880
```

The video is an H.264 encoding where (my understanding is a bit unclear here) it is something like a "raw" H.264 stream without timestamps.

My primary concern is to get video displayed with low latency. In that regard, the video is fine.

The issue is with the framerate and with the startup time.

The video source is emitting frames as soon as they are processed, so the frame rate is not constant. However, my experience is that as long as you specify a framerate larger than the max achievable frame rate of the source, then the viewer still looks fine. On the flipside, if the video source starts emitting frames at 60 fps, but I specify a framerate of 30, then the delay just sort of builds up in ffplay to the point where after 10 seconds, the video is 20 seconds behind. So the first question would be whether there is a way to get ffplay to use a variable framerate. The behavior I am looking for is "display a frame as soon as it is received over http".

In light of the aforementioned issue, the approach I have been taking is to simply specify a high framerate, which seems to work. However, there is an issue with this approach in the form of startup time. When I set the framerate to 10, the ffplay window starts in approx 3 seconds, but then quickly starts accruing a lag (so I can't do this). When I set the framerate to 100, the ffplay window takes 30 seconds (literally 30 seconds) to start, but then will not have any lag.

I have seen that ffmpeg has a `vsync` option that on the surface seems like it would allow you to set a variable framerate. However, ffplay doesn't seem to recognize this. I would also be willing to pipe the output of ffmpeg to a different window (I am running Ubuntu 18.04) if that is what must be done, but I would prefer not to have to recompile ffplay.

Comment: What is the average emission rate?

Comment: If the source is emitting approximately 30 fps, then I get the above characteristics (setting the ffplay framerate to 10 means about 3 seconds to startup, framerate of 100 means 30 seconds of startup).